# How to Print Text from ComboBox into a MessageBox

Tags: c#

Will this work using C#. I am trying to get the text out of a combobox to compare and use.  I just want to get the text that is selected in the combobox and put it in a string.

```
string myText = "";
myText = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
MessageBox.Show(myText);
```

I am obviously new, but could use some help.

Comment: What's wrong with the code, what's the question?

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: When do you exactly execute the code?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember this will work for you:

`myText = combobox1.Text;`

Comment: Even if this works it's not clear why OP's code does not work.

Comment: It might be. He wants the text from the ComboBox in a MessageBox but uses the SelectedItem. If the SelectedItem doesn't override the ToString method to return something useful he might have used the DisplayMember-Property to display some actual property. This Value than can be found in ComboBox.Text

Comment: So the same what OP's GetItemText does?! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var text = comboBox1.SelectedItem != null ? comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() : string.Empty;
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of combo box `DropDownStyle` do you use ? and if no item selected and just a text typed, do you wanna get the text ? The code below will return the item selected or text typed for default `DropDownStyle` (including empty text):

```
string myText = "";
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) 
  myText=comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
else
  myText = comboBox1.Text;
MessageBox.Show(myText);
```